# Disappearing data values in TDBEdit box in Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I'm inserting a new record into a DB table that I have opened and in Edit mode.  I have a form whereas my Delphi XE application has pre-populated some values into TDBEdit boxes.  When tabbing from one TDBEdit box to another on the form, the value from the next TDBEdit box is removed upon entering the box.  This is not how I would like the component to behave... I'd rather the value stay in the box.  The data is not stored in the table until issue a table.Post command.

How can I get the data to stay in the box upon entering the TDBEdit box?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should better put the values in the fields of the dataset instead of the DB controls. That is how it is supposed to work. The DB control will always take its contents from the field instance.

To pre-populate the values for new records use the OnNewRecord event of the dataset.

Comment: I need the user to key in data into boxes on a form and then post those values to a database.  Some of the boxes can be pre-populated with data already.  So what type of boxes should I be using on my form prior to posting to the database?

Comment: As I said: put the pre-populated values into the fields of the dataset - not into the edit controls. You can also access the fields from the db controls. For instance, a TDBEdit has a property Field. Assuming the TDBEdit is named myDBEdit and the datatype is string, you can set the value with `myDBEdit.Field.AsString := 'enter your value here'`.

Comment: Sorry in advance for the confusion on this... so I understand what you're saying for the pre-populated fields, but what object or input box type should I use for the fields in the dataset that do not have pre-populated values, and I want the user to enter input that will eventually get posted to the dataset?

Comment: You use the standard DBControls like DBEdit. If you call Insert or Append to a TDataSet all fields are cleared. Inside the OnNewRecord handler you fill in the default values you want to have. Then the user can fill in the remaining fields with the DBControl as well as change the ones with default values to his need. Then you call Post on the TDataSet and all field values are stored. I suggest reading the manual for database development with Delphi: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Developing_Database_Applications_Index

Comment: Thanks for all your help Uwe!